# Object conversion using generics

Tags: generics, kotlin, design-patterns, type-conversion, converters

I do have an object conversion task that scrumbles my mind ;)
Lets assume, I have three (or more) formats of a business objects

```
class MapA { /*some implementation */ }

class MapB { /*some implementation */ }

class MapC { /*some implementation */ }
```

In addition I have a "super object" that is stored in a data base and contains the superset of all properties of MapA, MapB and MapC.

```
class SuperMap { /* all implemented properties from all maps */ }
```

I now need to be able to convert from and to any map type. So My idea was to specify a specific Converter interface that converts a specific map to the super map.

```
interface Converter<F>{

    fun convertFrom(map: F): SuperMap
    fun convertTo(map: SuperMap): F

}
```

The owner of the several map types then only have to implement map type <-> super map

```
class MapAConverter: Converter<MapA> {

    override fun convertFrom(map: MapA): SuperMap {
        return SuperMap()
    }

    override fun convertTo(map: SuperMap): MapA {
        return MapA()
    }
}

/* more converters */
```

Finally, I thought about a service then does the following:
If the user wants to convert MapA to MapC, the service internally converts MapA -> SuperMap -> MapC, ...
that way I do not have to code out all possible combinations ...

```
class ConverterService
{
    private val converters = mutableMapOf<KType, Converter<T>>()

    fun <T>register(converter: Converter<T>){
        this.converters[T::class] = converter
    }

    fun <F, T>Convert(map: F): T{

        // F ... from map
        val conv1 = converters[F::class]
        if (conv1 == null)
            throw Exception("No converter for this type of map")

        // convert to super class
        val sc = conv1.convertFrom(map)

        // T ... to map
        val conv2 = converters[T::class]
        if(conv2 == null){
            throw Exception("No converter for this type of map")
        }

        // convert to desirect class
        return conv2.convertFrom(sc) as T
    }
}
```

But that doesnt work...

1. The converters hashmap does not know about T
2. val conv1 = converters[F::class] tells me that F::class needs to be reifeid and wants to make Convert to an inline function. If I do either, it gets even more complicated ...

My implementation idea was as follows:

```
fun main() {

    // register some converters
    var cs = ConverterService()
    cs.register(MapAConverter())
    cs.register(MapBConverter())
    cs.register(MapCConverter())

    // input is map a
    val ma = MapA()

    // i want map c
    val mc = cs.Convert<MapA, MapC>(ma)

}
```

Can that be achieved somehow? I am happy for any hint/ suggestion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `mutableMapOf<KClass<*>, Converter<*>>()` (meaning [`Converter` with some unknown type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections)).
2. As the error message says, you need `F` and `T` to be [reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) to use `F::class`:

   ```
   inline fun <reified F, reified T> Convert(map: F): T { ... }
   ```

   and you need it in `register` too. I am not sure why you consider it "even more complicated".
3. You need some slight changes inside `Convert`: cast the converters to have the proper type parameter instead of `*` and use `convertTo` at the end. I'd make a helper function

   ```
   private inline fun <reified T> converter(): Converter<T> {
       val result = converters[T::class]
       if (result == null) 
           throw Exception("No converter for ${T::class.qualifiedName}")
       else
           return result as Converter<T>
   }

   inline fun <reified F, reified T> Convert(map: F): T {
       // F ... from map
       val conv1 = converter<F>()
       // convert to super class
       val sc = conv1.convertFrom(map)

       // T ... to map
       val conv2 = converter<T>()
       // convert to desired class
       return conv2.convertTo(sc)
   }
   ```

Comment: How about converters map and register function? T::class isn't a KType.

Comment: Fixed (didn't check and assumed `KClass` extended `KType` like the Java version does).